# I am writing a controller to list the employee id and name in spring boot web flux. But getting the floating values as well in the list controller

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, controller, resultset

I have used JDBC template to retrieve the details from database and I have a field with float value with 0.0 in the db. I was expecting only the employee name and id with this get request but not sure why i am getting this float value as well in the controller.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thank You!

```
 public Flux<Emplotee> getAllEmployeeIdsAndName() {

        List<Employee> allEmployee = jdbcTemplate.query(Queries.GET_ALL_EMPLOYEE_IDS_NAME, new RowMapper<Employee>() {
            @Override
            public Employee mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setId(resultSet.getString("employee_id"));
                employee.setName(resultSet.getString("employee_name"));
                return employee;
            }
        });
        return Flux.fromIterable(allEmployee);
    }
```

Query used:

```
        private static final String GET_ALL_EMPLOYEE_IDS_NAME = "select  employee_id , employee_name from employee";
```

I want to exclude this score value from the list.

```
 {
        "score": 0.0,
        "employee_name": "John doe",
        "employee_id": "97e3-f566c43cac3e"
    }
```

public class Employee {

```
   @JsonProperty("id")
   private String employee_id;
   private String employee_name;
   private float score;
   public String getId() {
      return id;
    }
   public void setEmployeeId(String employee_id) {  
      this.id = id;  
    }
   public String getName() { 
      return name; 
    } 
   public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) { 
    this.name = name; 
    } 
   public float getScore() {
     return score; 
      }
   public void setScore(float score) { 
       this.score = score;
     }

}
```

Comment: please share the source code of `Employee` class.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with details. Don't add them in comments, it makes it very hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may used primitive `float` in `Employee` class. Default value of float is `0.0f`
Use wrapper class for float, ie `Float`.  The default value of `Float` is `null`. So you will get response as

```
   {
        "score": null,
        "employee_name": "John doe",
        "employee_id": "97e3-f566c43cac3e"
    }
```

**Note:** 
If you really want to ignore the property, then you can use **`@JsonIgnore`** annotation.`@JsonIgnore` is used to ignore the logical property used in serialization and deserialization. `@JsonIgnore` can be used at setter, getter or field.

```
public class Employee {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Float score;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setEmployeeId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setEmployeeName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Float getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(Float score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to include score in my response. As you can see my query its only getting the employee name and id . How can i exclude score from my get controller ?

Comment: Updated answer. You can use `@JsonIgnore` annotation. But at this time, while deserialization also, it wont accept the property.

Comment: follow this link for more information. https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonignore-jsonignoreproperties-and-jsonignoretype